# Революция и переворот

Tags: семантика, история

В чём вы видите различия между этими понятиями? Просьба не увлекаться копипастой исторических энциклопедий, поскольку как историку мне их мнение более-менее известно. Интересует скорей где проводят черту между этими явлениями на обывательском уровне.

Примеры "революций" и "переворотов" можете брать любые.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"Мятеж не может кончиться удачей. Если он победит - его зовут иначе", - так писал М. Волошин.

Слово "победит", вероятно, включает в себя понятие "перемена формации".

ПЕРЕВОРОТ - это когда меняется только верхушка власти, но более никаких кардинальных изменений не происходит. 
Свержение Петра III и восшествие на престол Екатерины II - это переворот.

Переворот может являться и часто является одним из этапов революции.

РЕВОЛЮЦИЯ - это когда происходят кардинальные изменения в социальном устройстве общества. Изредка бывает и без мятежа и переворота - РЕВОЛЮЦИЯ СВЕРХУ, когда революционные изменения происходят по инициативе властей, без их смены. 
Так что события как февраля, так и октября 1917 года - революции, хотя большевистский переворот тоже имел место.

Политические и социальные революции возникают как следствие нарастания противоречий в обществе на определенном этапе его развития, представляют собой наиболее острые формы борьбы между нарождающимися новыми и отживающими старыми формами общественных отношений.

В наше время всё упрощается, вернее, побеждает западный взгляд на эти вещи. Нас учили, что  революция- это формационный переворот. А вот во французской политической культуре, например, революция - это любой государственный переворот.

Comment: Так и не понял, разница-то есть?  
И еще, Людмила, я не знаю, когда и где писал такое Волошин, но он был явно не первым.  
Ибо еще в XVII Джон Харингтон писал:  
Treason doth never prosper: what’s the reason?  
For if it prosper, none dare call it treason.   
А то, что Вы процитировали, есть не что иное как "испорченный" перевод Маршака:  
Мятеж не может кончиться удачей,   
В противном случае его зовут иначе.

Comment: Ну, да, это вариант перевода Волошина. Просто первую строчку помнила-забила в поисковик - вышли эти строчки, а не Маршака. Общий смысл слов революция и переворот в социальной и политической жизни похож - смена власти, но в моём понимании есть разница: революция -кардинальные изменения в социальном устройстве общества, например,буржуазно-демократическая революция, социалистическая революция, меняются формации; переворот - меняется верхушка власти, а формация неизменна. В экономике таких различий нет-переворот в промышленности, революция - одинаково, коренные изменения.

Comment: Можете дать ссылку на источник этого "перевода"?
Я, конечно, не великий его знаток, но чтоб такое...

Answer (score 8):

Сперва о легитимности революций и переворотов. Они **вне**легитимны. Легитимность - это признание народом власти над собой. Т.е. легитимным правителем является тот, кому готовы подчиняться, а то каким образом он пришёл к власти (выборы, престолонаследие, гос. переворот, революция, выкрикнут из толпы) при этом дело десятое. Если часть населения перестаёт подчиняться своему правителю и отказывает ему в праве на власть, то происходит делегитимизация власти, в результате чего, если неповиновение продолжается, происходит переворот или революция. В чём разница?

Сперва нужно упомянуть то, что слово "переворот" для обозначения смены власти появилось в русском в XVIII веке как калька с французского "revolution", поэтому где-то до ХХ века особой разницы в понятиях нет.

Сейчас в отечественной истории и политологии принято эти понятия различать в зависимости от степени охвата населения и сопутствующих изменений. Если в результате силового и/или неконституционного захвата власти сменилась лишь правящая верхушка, то это называют переворотом, если произошли кардинальные изменения в общественном укладе - революция.

Скажем в связи с различием в словах сейчас среди историков ведётся дискуссия о том, является ли "Великая октябрьская революция" революцией или только переворотом. Сторонники первой точки зрения указывают на то, что изменения произошли кардинальные и из буржуазной республики, продекларированной целью революции Февральской перешли к социалистической, а изменения затронули всю бывшую империю и даже соседние страны. Однако приверженцы того, что это переворот указывают на то, что во-первых; большевики участвовали и в событиях февраля и на протяжении 17 года уже имели влияние на власть хотя бы в виде различных "Советов депутатов", т. е. большевики входили в верхушку власти и до Октября, во-вторых; предполагаемая Лениным структура общества в целом мало отличалась от того, чего хотело добиться "Временное правительство" (строить социализм мы начали только при Сталине, Ленин проповедовал госкапитализм), а в-третьих; в исторической науке не принято выделять отдельные перипетии в рамках одной революции (например, "якобинская диктатура" в рамках Великой французской революции) в новые революции.

Answer (score 4):

1.СЛОВАРНОЕ ЗНАЧЕНИЕ

В современных словарях слова ПЕРЕВОРОТ И РЕВОЛЮЦИЯ по своему значению имеют как сходство, так и различие:
РЕВОЛЮЦИЯ - коренной  переворот  в  жизни  ОБЩЕСТВА,  который приводит к  ликвидации предшествующего общественного и политического строя и установлению  новой  власти.
 ПЕРЕВОРОТ -  коренное  изменение  В  ГОСУДАРСТВЕННОЙ  ЖИЗНИ.  Революционный п.

2.ИСТОРИЯ

У обоих слов интересная история.

ПЕРЕВОРОТ – это словообразовательная калька 18 века слова revolution (франц.).  Переосмысление значений произошло позже.

И очень любопытно происхождение  слова РЕВОЛЮЦИЯ, как и слова ЭВОЛЮЦИЯ, которые в настоящее время противопоставляются друг другу.

В позднем средневековье слово РЕВОЛЮЦИЯ использовалось исключительно в астрономии и имело значение «возвращение небесного тела на прежний путь, на прежнее место: Volvo – качу, вращаю,  revolve – катить назад, re -  приставка со значением возобновления действия или движения в обратном направлении. В качестве политического термина слово впервые употребил Монтескье в 1748 году в труде «О духе законов». В России слово «революционер» стало известно с  19 века в связи с Французской революцией, в словарях с 1861 года.

Также ЭВОЛЮЦИЯ  - это развертывание (evolve – разворачиваю, раскрываю), термин  применялся для описания военных передвижений армии и флота. Эволюция как развитие общества отмечается в словарях только  с начала 20 века.

3.ВЫВОД

Поэтому «революция»  в прямом значении – это возвращение к началу нового витка в развитии общества, но совсем не переворот. (А эволюция – процесс разворачивание этого витка). Именно генетическое  различие слов "РЕВОЛЮЦИЯ И ПЕРЕВОРОТ" определило разное их значение, в том числе оценочное.

Реальные события не всегда можно оценить сразу: революция может начаться и с переворота, если в дальнейшем происходит не только смена государственное власти, но и коренные преобразования в обществе.

Comment: И всё же вы настаиваете, что слово французское, а не латынь? Ну да ладно. В энциклопедическом Словаре Ф. А. Брокгауза и И. А. Ефрона есть одна интереснейшая мысль: "Революция в собственном смысле слова происходит всегда вследствие движения, охватившего широкие круги народа, и состоит в том, что политическая власть переходит из рук одного общественного класса в руки другого". Переворот же, может ограничится сменой власти в рамках одного слоя общества, к примеру дворцовый переворот 1801г.

Comment: РЕВОЛЮЦИЯ восходит к позднелатинскому revolutio - возвращение, повторение, просто сначала это был астрономический термин, только потом произошло его переосмысление как во Франции, так и в России. (Так, в 1717 году в русском языке отмечено употребление этого слова, но с не очень ясным значением "отмена"). А что касается остального, то все верно. Есть государственные (дворцовые) перевороты, а есть революции, в которых принимают участие широкие массы, заинтересованные в коренных переменах.

Answer (score 2):

Революция – слово,  применяемое не только в политической среде. Революция сознания, сексуальная революция, духовная революция, революция в машиностроении, промышленности,  киноиндустрии и т.д.  Невзирая на то, что происходит оно от revolutio -   переворот, мы воспринимаем «революцию», как нечто значимое,  глобальное. Возможно,  потому и позаимствовали его из латинского языка, дабы в русском появилось более выразительное понятие,  нежели переворот. Не скажешь: переворот сознания, переворот сексуальный … Прыжок с переворотом – это да. 
   Говоря о политике, революция –  нечто романтическое, высокое, важное. Переворот же – приземлённое, преступное. Именно поэтому, сторонники событий октября 1917 года, назвали свои действия революцией, а противники – переворотом.

Comment: >Именно поэтому, сторонники событий октября 1917 года, назвали свои действия революцией, а противники – переворотом.

Ленин был противником событий октября 1917 года? В своих работах он часто использовал термин "Октябрьский переворот"?

Comment: Думаю, в сознании Ильича эти слова были лишь синонимами, потому использовались попеременно, дабы разнообразить свою речь. Он наверняка знал, как с латыни переводится "революция". В общественном сознании на даннам этапе нашего развития эти понятия постепенно отдаляются друг от друга.

Answer (score 1):

Если говорить о политике, т.е. о государственном перевороте, то никакой принципиальной разницы в семантике нет. Только стилистическая.

И то и другое означает смену власти нелегитимным (с точки зрения говорящего) путем. 
В "революцию" чаще закладывают одобрительный смысл, в "переворот" - негативный, хотя и не обязательно.

"Переворот" обычно воспринимается как нечто в конечном счете осуществленное, доведенное до конца, революция - не обязательно.  Но это тоже стилистика, да и не очень императивная...

Не знаю, что еще сказать. В той теме, где этот "переворот" впервые прозвучал, я *изначально* противопоставил его отнюдь не революции, а скорее легитимной смене, пусть и драматической по своей сути. Т.е. если уж говорить по тому поводу, то о сравнении (противопоставлении) переворота и ***эволюции***.

(+)
Пожалуй не лишне будет перепостить сюда из Вики:

*Государственный переворот — смена власти в государстве, осуществляемая обязательно ***с нарушением действующих на данный момент конституционных и правовых норм***, обычно с применением силы для захвата центров управления государством и осуществлением физической изоляции (иногда ареста или убийства) действующих его руководителей*** (Вики, курсив мой - b-s)
[Государственный переворот | ru.wikipedia.org](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82)

Можно спорить об авторитетности источника, но формальные определения там обычно все-таки адекватны. да оно, собственно, и не находит опровержения...

(+)

ГОСУДАРСТВЕННЫЙ ПЕРЕВОРОТ – внезапная ***нелегитимная*** смена правительства, предпринятая организованной группой для смещения или замены законной власти
(Энциклопедия Кругосвет, курсив мой - b-s)
[Государственный переворот | krugosvet.ru](http://www.krugosvet.ru/enc/gumanitarnye_nauki/sociologiya/GOSUDARSTVENNI_PEREVOROT.html)

Вообще не понимаю, что тут можно противопоставить, незаконность, нелегитимность - для меня тут ключевое слово.

Comment: Переворот необязательно происходит с нарушением правовых норм, например отстранение Хрущёва и Берии от власти, насколько помню произошли с соблюдением всех формальностей, однако, по сути, это перевороты. Так что Вики как обычно не совсем в теме.

Comment: Я пользуюсь определеним из Вики.
Что касается Хрущева и прочих, то весьма трудно говорить о соблюдении нормах там, где нормы изначально не были прописаны.