# Значение слова "революция" в отношении политических изменений

Tags: значение-слов, выбор-слов

Я долгое время думал, что револючия - это государственный переворот (поскольку обычно это слово употребляется именно по отношению к октябрьской революции), некое событие, случающееся за несколько дней. Однако всегда чувствовалось некоторое противоречие с определением этого слова "радикальное, коренное, глубокое, качественное изменение" - какое глубокое изменение можент произойти за день? Впоследствии я узнал, что, например, в отношении кубинской революции это слово имее другое значение - там револючия все еще в процессе, уже более полусотни лет. В советских лозунгах и газетах двадцатых годов оно также, кажется, имело другое значение - что-то вроде "революция победит" - то есть, они подразумевали, что революция всё еще в процессе. Как исторически получилось, что это слово поменяло значение, и как его нужно понимать по отношениею к государственным переворотам - как событие или как долгий процесс?

Comment: Не вижу причин ни считать, что слово поменяло значение, ни то, что по отношению к Кубе это значение в чем-то особенное. Вы, видимо, ошибочно полагаете, что "переворот"  - во времени это событие "точечное", мгновенное.

Comment: Нет тут дубликата. Почитайте.

Comment: @behemothus Я полностью прочитал. Там ведется обсуждение примерно того же, растолковывается история слова. Не вижу, чего бы можно было добавить тут.

Comment: Плохо читали. Там вопрос по-другому стоит. То, что Марк Из сбился на знакомую ему проблему, это его личный подход.

Comment: Мой вопрос, я и решаю, дубликат это или нет. Мой вопрос звучал в точности как "Как исторически получилось, что это слово поменяло значение, и как его нужно понимать по отношениею к государственным переворотам - как событие или как долгий процесс?" - и всё это затронуто в ответах на дублированнй вопрос.

Comment: *Мой вопрос, я и решаю, дубликат это или нет.* - Вы ошибаетесь. Решает в любом случае сообщество. Впрочем, Вы можете изменить вопрос так, чтобы сомнений не было.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я уже задавал подобный вопрос на этом ресурсе и даже опубликовал собственный ответ на него, ссылку привожу ниже. Если обобщить в контексте вашего вопроса, то изначально "пере-ворот" - это калька с французского "re-volution" и вплоть до  XXв. разницы между этими словами нет. Сам Ленин называл события октября 1917 г. и так, и так. В советской историографии появилось различие: революция - глобальное изменение ("есть у революции начало, нет у революции конца"), перевороты - насильственная смена верхушки власти. По этой причине современные историки спорят можно ли события октября 1917 г. считать революцией или это переворот (подробнее в моём на ответе по ссылке ниже). 
Правда сейчас уже началась тенденция к обратному сращиванию значений революции и переворота, уже в связи с влиянием английского. Большинство так называемых цветных революций, формально должны были бы быть отнесены к переворотам.

Подробнее можете посмотреть в моём [вопросе](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/31868/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82).

Comment: Как тогда не понимал, так и сейчас не понимаю. А откуда вообще появилась идея о двух значениях? Есть хоть один словарь, которые эти значения разделяет?  *РЕВОЛЮЦИЯ, -и; ж. [от лат. revolutio - переворот] 1. Коренной переворот во всей социально-экономической структуре общества, приводящий к смене общественного строя.* (Кузнецов) Второе значение - уже переносное, не связанное с социально-экономическим устройством. А первое - хоть так крути, хоть этак - ну нет разделения на одномоментный и перманентный переворот...

Comment: @behemothus, есть разделение на коренное и не коренное изменение. Переворот затрагивает только верхушку, а революция - всё общество. Подробнее в энциклопедии "Кругосвет" http://www.krugosvet.ru/enc/gumanitarnye_nauki/sociologiya/GOSUDARSTVENNI_PEREVOROT.html?page=0,0

Comment: Коренное и некоренное - это понять можно. Но мы же не об этом сейчас?! И то и другое может быть одномоментным и растянутым во времени.

Comment: @МаркИз Благодарю, это примерно то, что я искал.

Answer (score 2):

Не меняло это слово своего значения – какое было, такое и осталось. Просто удобнее говорить, что, например, Октябрьская революция произошла в октябре 1917 года или даже 25 октября (7 ноября) 1917 года. Понимая, естественно, что за несколько дней никакого "коренного изменения" произойти не может и имея ввиду лишь начало процесса. Но все же имея в виду, что в отличие от эволюции революция – процесс гораздо более быстрый, скачкообразный.

Comment: Так все же это процесс или событие? И каковы примерные пременные рамки?

Comment: И то и другое. И оеволюцтонное событие и Революционный процесс имеют право на существование в рамках понятия "революция".  Вы с Марком что-то уж очень специфическое для узкой филологии смотрите.